# Careers profile help text is not selectable

Tags: bug, status-declined, jobs, user-interface, accessibility

Repro steps:

Start editing your Careers 2.0 profile.
Select a field and notice help text on the right.
Try to select the help text with your mouse.

Unexpected result: The text disappears as the focus leaves the text box you were editing

Expected result: I should be able to select this text. For screen readers, specifically Mac OS X's built in speech capabilities, it is necessary to select the text to be spoken.

This occurs in (at least) Safari 5.0.3

Comment: I can confirm this also happens in Chrome (10.0.648.133) on Windows.

Comment: We won’t be fixing this one immediately, it’s not a common use case.